# What does に in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

> 失敗を適切に処理する**に**は、失敗の経験が役に立つ

what does に mean when it is placed after a sentence? can you give me a source so that I can learn this usage further

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not “〜に” but　“〜には”. This usage can never occur without “〜は”.

It's actually very similar in nuance to the infinitive in English, the sentence means:

> Experience with failure is useful **to properly deal with failure**.

Other such sentences can be:

> 恋と呼ぶには気持ち悪い = It's disgusting to call this love.

> ものを買うには金が必要だ = One needs money to buy things.

It's often said to indicate a purpose, but much as with English “to” that's not necessarily the case as one can see in the case of “恋と呼ぶには気持ち悪い”

Note that one can not use it like this:

> パソコンを買うにはここに来た != I came here to buy a p.c..

For that sentence one must use:

> パソコンを買いにここに来た

Attaching “〜に” to the continuative form of a verb. In general it's only used for abstract, general statements of purpose, not concrete instances.

https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-ni-wa-meaning/

Comment: you explanation is good,but I can't see any formal source talk about this usage.all of source say するには indicate purpose,but in example I give,it is apparently not,it is more like "to"  in "It's disgusting to call this love." can you any source confirm this usage? the link you give don't mention this usage

Comment: @CN.hitori I can't find a confirmation but it's actually the title of a work of fiction. I know many sources say it always indicates purpose but it would, for that title not make any sense for it to indicate purpose, nor would “It's disgusting, in order to call this love.” really ever make sense. It's easy to find citations on the internet of things such as “夏はオニカサゴを釣るにはいい時期ですよ” or “"夜ぐっすり眠るにはいいことだ” which clearly do not indicate purpose by context but simply. “It's a nice thing to sleep soundly at night.”.